# How do I create an Apache mod_rewrite rule that works with urlencoded values?

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I'm using the php function urlencode http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php to encode a GET parameter `$_GET['test']`

I want to use an apache rewrite rule to rewrite urls like `website.com/%CE%A6` to `website.com/index.php?test=%CE%A6`

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9])/?$ /index.php?test=$1 [NC,L]`

What is a regex that can be used in place of `[a-z0-9]` to accept the range of valid characters returned by  the `urlencode` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just capture anything until you get a `/` with a `RewriteCond` to prevent looping:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?test=$1 [QSA,L]
```